# Storing image in database directly vs storing image in server and a link to it in database

Tags: struts2

I am creating a registration page in struts2 where users need to upload photo. 
When I wrote action class for it, I found two options.

1. Storing image in database directly.
2. Storing image in server and a link to it in database.

I want to know which option is better and why.

Comment: What did you try? Do you have a code example?

Comment: I tried first option,directly to database as a BLOB file.Uploading is working.but showing it in user page is not working.we are not allowed to copy codes in office,so i can't upload the sample.

Comment: sorry to inform you that without it your question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: ok.thanks for your replay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pro Database:
The images will always be together with the rest of the data.
If you need to cluster / load balance your server its easy as you don't need a central file server.
Backup and Restoring the database restores all images.

Cons Database:
Your database could blow out in size making maintenance tasks painfull.
a busy site will kill your database performance as you have to continuously move the same data out if the database.
you cant use  a file system to manage the files or any nr of very useful file management commands.
At some point you will build a caching layer with a link to the database row.

I have implemented both approaches now I always link to the database and leave files in the file system the little extra work for setting up a fileserver when you need to load balance is worth all the benefits in eas and flexibility you gain in administration and performance tuning etc.

Comment: So.. storing link is the better option ?

Comment: better in the long run. your application will be a little harder to install cause you got to manage file paths, but you will end up with a faster easier to maintain system. so yes store a link. better yet just store the file name, and define the path in your application config / settings.